# How to make flash light blink while pressing a button

Tags: android, eclipse

I am fairly new to android and I am trying to make flash light blink when the button is pressed. The code i am using is for simply switching on and off the flashlight. I am trying to add another button which will make the flashlight blink in a certain pattern. Is it possible that we set the pattern parameters just like we do in vibrating in a pattern

My code is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private Camera camera;
    ImageButton flashLightSwitchImage;
    private boolean isFlashlightOn;
    Parameters params;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flashLightSwitchImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashlight_switch);

        boolean isCameraFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if (!isCameraFlash) {
            showCameraAlert();
        } else {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        }

        flashLightSwitchImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isFlashlightOn) {

                    setFlashLightOff();
                } else {
                    setFlashLightOn();

                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void showCameraAlert() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Error loadin Flash!")
                .setMessage("Flash Not Available in this Device")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();

    }}}}

This code right here is working fine but it simply switches on and off the flashlight.

I want to introduce another button which makes the flash light blink in a pattern.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for blinking the flash. You can edit this to support your required pattern

```
    String myString = "01010101010101";
     long blinkDelay 50; //Delay in ms 
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) { 
    if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') { 
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON); 
    } else {
     params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
     } try { 
    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace(); 
    } }
```

Comment: how do i really implement it with a button, facing some errors

Comment: I am unable to implement it with my ontouchlistener button, @Fahim could you please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

use this code on the listener of your button

```
getCamera();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String myString = "01010101010010101010101";
            long blinkDelay =500;
            for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
                if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                   //params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                    turnOnFlash();
                } else {
                  //  params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    turnOffFlash();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

and define this code outside on create method

```
 private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            //    Log.d("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}




/*
 * Turning On flash
 */
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
       // playSound();

        params =  camera.getParameters();

        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
       // toggleButtonImage();
    }

}

/*
 * Turning Off flash
 */
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        //playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
      //  toggleButtonImage();
    }}
```

Comment: if face any issue ask for it